# Woocommerce: couldn’t import products with lots of attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have few products with around 150 different Global attributes in CSV. When I tried to import it, it’s stuck on ‘Your products are now being imported…’ screen with 0% completion. If I reduce the attributes to around 115 types, it does import successfully. Woocommerce Plugin author replied me that there's no limit on attributes import, The only limit is dictated by your server.
I have increased the memory and max execution time but that didn't help. Please help me solve this issue.
Thanks.

Woocommerce version: 4.5.2
WordPress version:5.5.1

Comment: can you tr by max_input_var in php.ini?

Comment: I did change max_input_var but was not working and silly me I forgot to uncomment it. After uncommenting max_input_var and changed to 3000, It worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Nice to hear. I am happy that your code is working now.